# debugging a symfony application with eclipse in windows

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

Trying to setup and debug a symfony application in windows using Eclipse PDT.

- installed symfony plugin as well from http://symfony.dubture.com/
- installed xdebug dll and updated the php.ini file to reflect the same
- I also have xdebug helper chrome installed

I run the app via the command

```
php app/console server:run
```

How do I make this break into the IDE? I looked around for simple steps and could find none. I would love to get some pointers as to how best to debug a Symfony app with Eclipse.

**Debugging with Eclipse**

Also, in Eclipse I see debugger set to XDebug(Symfony). I am not sure what I should set as the local web root and base URL. I key in 127.0.0.1:8000 as the base URL and the web root as the code directory. When I click debug as symfony action it still asks me for a index file. If I enter the controller file it just does nothing.  The debug properties screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Did you configured xdebug for remote debugging?: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug#Configuration

Comment: Yes. I did. I also have remote debugging enabled in the php.ini file. I am able to debug fine with phpstorm.

Comment: I didn't realized before. Switch to standard XDebug. XDebug (Symfony) not working for now.